# How can I copy updates from one windows 7 to another?

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

I have some windows 7 systems and a slow internet connection, is there anyway I can copy downloaded updates (security) from one machine to another and make them install on the second machine?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. What have you attempted so far? Any research lead you in a particular direction?

Comment: Generally speaking, you cannot. updates are retrieved based on the exact state of the machine, and most machines are not identical. This is expecially concerning when it comes to update replacements, which are common for MS.

Answer (score 0):

It is no longer trivial to download updates from MS, but it *can* be done:

1. Note the Knowledge Base (KB) numbers in the *Windows Update* list. If you simply go to the MS site, though, you often get the notice "This update is available from Windows Update. See How to get an update through Windows Update."
2. Check in an Internet search engine for the KB number and how to download the **appropriate** *Windows Update Standalaone Package*. For example, for *KB3035583*, see [Download KB3035583 without using Windows Update?](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_update/download-kb3035583-without-using-windows-update/a9fded97-a62a-4f24-9168-3cac1b30a878?auth=1), which include a link to the [installer package](http://download.windowsupdate.com/d/msdownload/update/software/updt/2015/05/windows6.1-kb3035583-x64_d6308e28c41fcbd15695343d83709ed1c4bf5812.msu). *Save* the file, rather than run it immediately.
3. Distribute the .msu file(s) to other machines and install there.

**N.B.** There may be different versions of the installer for different configurations (version of Windows, language etc.) If the wrong installer were to be used, it could trash the OS.

Though I wish there were a better answer, MS apparently does not want the user in control of the update process any longer. As an extreme case, Windows 10 no longer gives you an option to defer updates and install them manually, if the PC can connect to the MS servers.

Comment: Microsoft does provide http://catalog.update.microsoft.com to search and download windows updates just a lot of people do not know about it. And Windows 10 does provide the ability to defer it in domain environments via group policy.

Comment: But not Windows 10 Home, without hacks.

Answer (score 0):

1. From the department of overkill.  You could setup a WSUS server, and it would retrieve the updates and the 2 PC would be setup to get them from there.
2. From it might work department, setup a caching server the squid.  You download the updates one 1 PC, and hopefully the caching server will feed it to the other machine.